# Sanwa YX360TRF cannot zero-ohm adjust

Tags: analog, resistance, multimeter

I have a 10 years old but slightly used Sanwa YX360TRF analog multimeter I hide in a cabinet I removed batteries. I used it, very rarely and I took extra care to remove batteries when not in used. A month ago, I put fresh new batteries on it, and then I noticed that I am unable to zero-ohm adjust in the usual way that I'm able to do in the past. When I short the probes, the needle only moves very lightly, no amount of ohm-adjuster can zero-ohm it. The DC measure is still fine. The fuse is fine.

I just bought a new Fluke 17B+ DMM and I wanted to diagnose and fix the analog one so that I'll have an extra analog meter. I opened-up the Sanwa YX360TRF and checked the insides, looked shiny and no visible suspect. How do I fix this analog meter?

Comment: Check your fresh new batteries. It is not that expensive to replace. Try to get the service manual and proceed from there. You should be able to find it online, I did not try..

Comment: IS one battery backwards?  or dead?  This is really an Ohm's Law test and if defection can' make it far past zero, that's the voltage  R=V/I with a constant V

Comment: You will see the battery voltage at the probe tips if you connect them to a DMM. If it's wrong or absent, start cleaning switches and connectors.

Comment: @Gil you are spot on! I didn't suspected it coz the battery when taken out still measured fresh strong. But when connected to meter, gave 2.5 for the two AAA. I bought new AAA batteries, and voila, zero-ohms achieved!

Comment: Adding here, that new batteries fixed the case for my YX360TRF (bought 2006). But I have another much older YX360TRe (bought in 1995) still on-going investigation.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Have a great year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your fresh new batteries. It is not that expensive to replace. Try to get the service manual and proceed from there. You should be able to find it online,